# is there any way that I can serve my ".next" folder without using next.js?

Tags: reactjs, docker, deployment, next.js, pm2

I know how to reduce the size, I should remove dev time dependencies, another option is easy to find on the internet. But the real question comes while serving the next.js app. I deploy the website on production through pm2 using `next start`. What is really happening is that `next start` won't work without dev dependencies and which affects the size of the docker image. Is there any way that I can serve my `.next` folder without using next.js? This will reduce the massive size of the docker image.

Comment: `next start` does work without dev dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yarn install --production=true` to ignore `devDependencies` and only install regular `dependencies`.

Using this, you can install production dependencies first in a temporary folder, then copy the dependencies to the app folder and remove the temp folder.

Here's an example Dockerfile:

```
# Install production dependencies
WORKDIR /tmp/app
COPY ./package.json ./package.json
COPY ./yarn.lock ./yarn.lock
RUN yarn install --production=true
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/web && cp -a ./node_modules /home/node/web/

# Build project
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production=false
RUN yarn run build
RUN cp -a ./dist /home/node/web/

# Clean up
RUN rm -rf /tmp/app

# Run next app
WORKDIR /home/node/web
CMD NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/.bin/next
```

Comment: as i mentioned that @Acidic9 i'm not able to run my project without dev dependancies because next uses that during time of deployment. main moto is to serve .next folder without next.js.

Comment: @VimLeSai what does next use from dev dependencies? Just next itself? If so maybe you can just move next from dev to normal dependencies

Comment: @VimLeSai `"next", "react", "react-dom"` should all be in `dependencies` rather than `devDependencies`